# Font Awesome Displays Content Number instead of Icon

Tags: css, font-awesome

The code below, which replaces the bullet points on my site with Font Awesome icons, works fine in my regular stylesheet.  But I need to put it in custom.css to bypass my CDN.  When I do that the content no. - F12b - appears instead of the desired icon.  Any pointers?  Thank you!

```
ul.circled li:before, 
.widget_categories ul li:before,
.post-content ul li:before,
aside ul li:before {

font-family:'FontAwesome';
content:"\f12b";

 }
```

Comment: Do you have a jsfiddle?

Comment: "Bypass my CDN"...what does that mean.

Comment: Sorry I don't have a jsfiddle. About bypassing my CDN - I just need to override the code in my regular stylesheet because when it is served via the Content Delivery Network the web fonts don't display.  Any code I put in custom.css doesn't get served via the CDN so I need the code in there.  Hope that explains?

Comment: OK I made one but I don't think it's helpful as it doesn't replicate the problem.  The code appears to be sound but displays wrongly when I put it where I need it to be.    http://jsfiddle.net/debsied/L28cofe8/

Comment: Maybe someone knows why it would display the content number, or indeed anything I put in between the inverted commas in the content: selector?  It takes whatever is written there literally instead of displaying the icon.

Comment: If the CSS file is intercepted by some other facility between the server and the end user, maybe the backslash is being parsed in ways that it shouldn't. Try writing a double backslash, or, just put the character  in instead of the numerical code.