# Pseudo element before content ignoring \ in browser

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

I have this really basic issue I am trying to solve for a while now. I am running out of all ideas.

I have a css pseudo-element before that I am styling like this.

```
#fPhone::before{
    color: #78be20;
    content: "\e622";
    font-family: icons;
}
```

But on the browser it just prints out 622. When I inspect the pseudo tag, I see

```
content: "e622";
```

If I try adding "\" in the debugger it works but for some reason it doesn't pick it up from css.

I am running out of reasons that could be causing this.

Comment: Can you make an example snippet that demonstrates the issue? It doesn't happen in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/ceh82vz0/), so there must be some context that gets in the way.

Comment: No. Its a icon font that looks like mobile phone. Its hows up correctly when I add "\" in the debugger

Comment: Also, I doubt I'll be able to create a snippet for it since the font-family:icons I have has its own svg ttf and woff files

Comment: You can use `@font-face` in a snippet...

Comment: By the way, this question looks a lot like http://stackoverflow.com/q/30375344/1016716 but I have no idea if the problem is the same. Or the solution. So not closing as a duplicate just yet.

Comment: Are you running your CSS through some kind of preprocessor? Also, you say *But on the browser it just prints out 622*--are you sure it is not `e622` it is printing out?

Comment: In addition to verifying that the current value of `content` for the `#fPhone:;before` pseudo-element is `e622` instead of the desired `\e622`, use the style inspector to verify **where** (what rule) that value is coming from. It is conceivable that there is some other rule in your CSS somewhere which was mistakenly written as `content: "e622";` which is taking precedence.

Comment: @torazaburo Since the `e` gets consumed, we must conclude it's a preprocessor that uses `\e` as an escape code, otherwise it would just emit the unescaped `e`. So, does anybody know any system where `\e` is a valid escape code?

Answer (score 0):

Sure you imported the icon-font correctly and are using the proper hexcode? Below proof that it works as you may expect...

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons");

#fPhone::before{
    color: #78be20;
    content: "\e0cd"; /* different code, but same effect */
    font-family: 'Material Icons';
}

/* class is pre-defined in @import (default <parent>color, 24px)*/
.material-icons { color: #78be20; font-size: 16px; }

/*
  find the codes and ligatures for Material Icons at:
https://github.com/google/material-design-icons/blob/master/iconfont/codepoints

*/
```

```html
<div id="fPhone"> a phone</div>
<div><i class="material-icons">phone</i> using ligature name</div>
```

Comment: Sure, this works. But it's doubtful that the problem is the importing of the font or the proper hexcode. Neither would explain why apparently the `content: "\e622"` is getting corrupted to `e622` or `622`.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer. All it does is say "look it works", just like in the first comment above.

Comment: @Mr Lister, maybe not one you may like, but this is to user3861559, who thusfar has not eleborated/reacted on previous comments and suggestions. Now the occasional passer by can at least read that it is the proper approach and user3861559 has an alternative icon-font (s)he can try. So, please lets not go into a semantics discussion.